# Compatibility of Beck Chevalley condition: sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, l-adic-sheaves

Given a (not necessarily Cartesian) square of spaces
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @>g>> \overline{X} \\
@VVfV @VV\overline{f}V \\
Y @>\overline{g}>> \overline{Y}
\end{CD}$$
does the following
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\overline{g}^* @>\epsilon_f>> f_*f^*\overline{g}^* @= f_*g^*\overline{f}^* \\
@V\epsilon_{\overline{f}}VV @. @A\eta_{\overline{f}}AA \\
\overline{g}^*\overline{f}_*\overline{f}^* @>\epsilon_f>> f_*f^* \overline{g}^*\overline{f}_*\overline{f}^* @= f_*g^*\overline{f}^*\overline{f}_*\overline{f}^*
\end{CD}
$$
commute?

By space I mean either scheme/stack/prestack and the second diagram occurs in $\text{QCoh}(-)$, or a more restrictive class of spaces like Artin stacks and the diagram occurs in the category of $\ell$-adic sheaves, or some sheaf theory with the six functors.

The right-up composition $\overline{g}^*\overline{f}^*\to f_*g^*$ is called the Beck-Chevalley composition, and a version of this question appears in 4.1.1 of ["Ambidexterity"](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ephaine/files/Ambidexterity_4.pdf) by Haine, but it has additional assumptions of "ambidexterity" on the maps, which one might hope could be dropped for the above question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true in complete generality. The outer rectangle in the diagram below is the diagram in question. I have duplicated $f_*g^*\bar{f}^*$ and added two more $\varepsilon_{\bar{f}}$.
The left and middle square commute because everything is natural. The right triangle commutes because of the zigzag identity for the $\bar{f}_* \dashv \bar{f}^*$ adjunction.

[image: 1]